# Access violation when running FHIRserver

Tags: hl7-fhir

I downloaded the fhir server from http://www.healthintersections.com.au/FhirServer/.

When I run the server with the following command "fhirserver –debug" I get following error:

```
2015-11-27--------------------------------
12:41:17 FHIR Service 1.0.2 (DSTU2). Using ini file c:\Program Files\FHIRServer\fhirserver.ini with stack dumps on
12:41:17 Using FHIR Specification at C:\Program Files\FHIRServer\spec
12:41:17 Database mssql://xx.xx.xx.xx/fhir
12:41:17 Load DB Terminologies
12:41:17  - done
12:41:17 Load Loinc from C:\ProgramData\FHIRServer\loinc.cache
12:41:17  - done
12:41:17 Load User Sub-system
12:41:17 Load & Cache Store: 
12:41:19 Load Validation Pack from C:\Program Files\FHIRServer\spec\validation-min.xml.zip
12:41:24 EAccessViolation: Access violation at address 00000000010895D3 in module 'FHIRServer.exe'. Read of address 0000000000000038

(0000000000C885D3){FHIRServer.exe} [00000000010895D3] UcumServices.TUcumServices.SetCommonUnits + $13
(0000000000040DEB){FHIRServer.exe} [0000000000441DEB] System.SysUtils.GetExceptionObject + $EB
(00000000002032C7){FHIRServer.exe} [00000000006042C7] JclHookExcept.DoExceptFilter + $E7
(0000000000203595){FHIRServer.exe} [0000000000604595] JclHookExcept.HookedExceptObjProc + $15
(000000000000F429){FHIRServer.exe} [0000000000410429] System.@DelphiExceptionHandler + $289
(000000000002805D){ntdll.dll   } [000000007785905D] Unknown function at RtlDecodePointer + $AD
(0000000000017C0F){ntdll.dll   } [0000000077848C0F] Unknown function at RtlUnwindEx + $BBF
(000000000004C948){ntdll.dll   } [000000007787D948] KiUserExceptionDispatcher + $2E
(0000000000C885D3){FHIRServer.exe} [00000000010895D3] UcumServices.TUcumServices.SetCommonUnits + $13
(0000000000CB1B3B){FHIRServer.exe} [00000000010B2B3B] TerminologyServerStore.TTerminologyServerStore.SeeSpecificationResource + $15B
(0000000000E27058){FHIRServer.exe} [0000000001228058] ServerValidator.TFHIRServerValidatorContext.SeeResource + $58
(0000000000ADF007){FHIRServer.exe} [0000000000EE0007] FHIRProfileUtilities.TValidatorServiceProvider.Load + $67
(0000000000ADE650){FHIRServer.exe} [0000000000EDF650] FHIRProfileUtilities.TValidatorServiceProvider.LoadFromDefinitions + $2C0
(0000000000EED84B){FHIRServer.exe} [00000000012EE84B] FHIRDataStore.TFHIRDataStore.Create + $14BB
(0000000000F1E89C){FHIRServer.exe} [000000000131F89C] FHIRRestServer.TFhirWebServer.Create + $9FC
(0000000000F47699){FHIRServer.exe} [0000000001348699] FHIRServerApplicationCore.TFHIRService.InitialiseRestServer + $49
(0000000000F45B01){FHIRServer.exe} [0000000001346B01] FHIRServerApplicationCore.TFHIRService.CanStart + $81
(000000000025B32E){FHIRServer.exe} [000000000065C32E] SystemService.TSystemService.InternalExecute + $6E
(000000000025AFFF){FHIRServer.exe} [000000000065BFFF] SystemService.TSystemService.DebugExecute + $4F
(000000000025BCD5){FHIRServer.exe} [000000000065CCD5] SystemService.TSystemService.Execute + $1F5
(0000000000F45131){FHIRServer.exe} [0000000001346131] FHIRServerApplicationCore.ExecuteFhirServer + $B31
(0000000000F63F55){FHIRServer.exe} [0000000001364F55] FHIRServerDev.FHIRServerDev + $75
(0000000000014A4D){kernel32.dll} [0000000077725A4D] BaseThreadInitThunk + $D
(000000000002A831){ntdll.dll   } [000000007785B831] RtlUserThreadStart + $21

12:41:24 Exception in Service Execution: 

Access violation at address 00000000010895D3 in module 'FHIRServer.exe'. Read of address 0000000000000038 
[EAccessViolation]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ucum is not configured in the ini fil at c:\Program Files\FHIRServer\fhirserver.ini.

[ucum]
source=C:\work\fhirserver\Exec\ucum-essence.xml

where ucum-essence.xml is from http://unitsofmeasure.org

Comment: I got the following errors for two units:
    No Handler for [degRe].
    No Handler for [m/s2/Hz^(1/2)].

I commented them out and it works fine now. Thanks @Grahame for your answer.